# How to use IntersectionObserver to check if page is at top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I'm trying to check if page is at the top using IntersectionObserver

We are at the top of the page

- if haven't scrolled more than 60px down `document.documentElement.scrollTop < 60`.
- or if any part of the red box is visible (I just made the red box to show where I want the top area of the page to be considered)

A: If we are at the top of the page, it's suppose to `console.log('we are at the top')`.

B: If we are not at the top of the page, it's suppose to `console.log('we are not at the top')`.

**Problem**

The problem is that it is printing we are at the top when the red box is not visible.

```js
const root = document.querySelector("#root");

const firstSection = document.querySelectorAll("section")[0];

const onIntersect = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting && document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 60) {
      console.log("WE ARE AT THE TOP");
    } else {
      console.log("WE ARE NOT AT THE TOP");
    }
  });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect, {
  root: root,
});

observer.observe(firstSection);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#root {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.red-box {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid red;
}

.bg-blue {
    background: blue;
}

.bg-green {
    background: green;
}

.bg-purple {
    background: purple;
}

.py-60 {
  padding: 40rem 0;
}
```

```html
  <div id="root">
      <div class="red-box"></div>

      <section class="bg-blue py-60"></section>

      <section class="bg-green py-60"></section>

      <section class="bg-purple py-60"></section>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are observing the first `section` but it is present inside the div with the id root so they always intersect. Shouldn't `root` be the `body` element? And I think you want to observe the red box and not one of the sections.

Comment: Yes, the root should be the body element. I just made the red box as a demonstration of where I would like the top area to be. Let's imagine it's not there

Comment: @RameshReddy I nested the stuff in a root because the code is being rendered in an iframe on stackoverflow I believe and it caused some issues

Comment: Why not observe the red box? You can use the 60px height like you're doing now and remove the border. I get that you have added the box to indicate the area that needs to be considered as the top but I think the observer can use it for the same reason.